# Is my javascript wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Very simple javascript that doesn't work.

I want the DIV to hide on mouse over. index.html and script.js are in the same folder. I am opening this in Chrome.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script> type='text/javascript' src='script.js' </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    Hello world
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').mouseenter(function () {
        $('div').hide();
    });
});
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: check your syntax at `<script> type...`

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>`

Comment: You must also include the JQuery source file. Otherwise `$()` and similar functions will not be defined.

Comment: Yeah, you're missing a `>`.

Comment: Beware, with this solution you will hide ALL divs on the page when you hover on one!

Comment: The answer is "NO" but your inclusion of Javascript libraries (jQuery and yours) IS wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

`<script> type='text/javascript' src='script.js' </script>`

to this:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>`

'type' and 'src' are parameters of the script tag, not what goes inside it.

Also, make sure you're including the jquery library in your HTML, or your script won't work because it doesn't know what `$` means.

Comment: Thanks, everything works! Back to learning :)